# jQuery script doesn't work fully well, alert doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery script:

```
$('input[name="add-post"]').on('click', function(form) {
    form.preventDefault();
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add-post',
        data: $('form.new-post').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        succes: function(data)
        {
            alert('123');

        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert('321');
        }
    });
});
```

And technically it works as it should.
Ajax goes to add-post php script, post is added to database.
Whole PHP script is done as it should.

But

`alert('123');`

Alert doesn't show up.
No 123.
No 321.
There is no alert.

Why this doesn't work? Despite PHP's script by ajax did all good.

(note: no information in console chrome after submit)

---

Some additional information:

When duplicate post is submitted (already exist in DB) 321 alert is shown.

But still no 123 alert.
When it is success.

Comment: If your PHP script doesn't **return valid JSON** the ajax call just times out

Comment: You forgot the second 's' in "success".

Comment: oh god... >.>.... figured it out 2-4 seconds before your answer @hRdCoder ugh :( . There should be errors or something... at least eh

Comment: But thank you very much @hRdCoder nice eye

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I caught it when I did. :)

Comment: There's no errors since `succes` is a valid json-key. The `$.ajax`-function is simply not using it for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### use this

success: function(data)